# upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04_ Update problem

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

After upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 I got the following two problems.
1. When I do sudo apt-get update I got:

```
W: <http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease>: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: <us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease>: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: <us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease>: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: <archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg>: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

2. There is no wifi connection.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you in advance and best regards

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to worry about the message. It is just a warning. SHA1 hashing algorithm is being deprecated. Below link has more information regarding this.

https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. What about Wifi connection?